Confusion about lemma 18.9 in Lee’s introduction to smooth manifolds (a map that is smooth on each face on a simplex is smooth)
   In the proof of the lemma, during the induction step, a new function is chosen. However, this new function ignores the k-th coordinate in the input of two terms. My confusion is that even if a point is in the domain of the function, the same point with k coordinate zero might not be in the domain. Is there somethingI’m missing.3
